# Addressing PDF Splitting Issues with Large Backend-Generated Content

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf

The problem arises when attempting to split PDFs generated from the backend, where large content is involved. This content, dynamically generated, results in PDFs that don't split as intended. so i need split in half of the Advice i need to do in split in half with out enter full content to next page

[image]

i need to split the advice text area in half show in 2 page .